# Fix Account issues after removing DC from server with IIS?

Tags: permissions, iis-7.5, domain-controller

We recently upgraded our single-domain Windows network by adding two new servers.  We promoted them both to domain controllers and removed the domain controller from our webserver (which was set up back when we had only one server).  This server (windows 2008 R2) ran IIS 7.5 and hosted Sharepoint and Asp.net pages.

The new domain controllers are both GC and work perfectly.

Now, when we removed the Domain Controller role, the permissions got screwed up ([Microsoft knows this happens](http://blogs.technet.com/b/abizerh/archive/2009/07/16/should-iis-be-installed-on-domain-controller.aspx)).  So now I want to fix it.

Before, my websites and sharepoint were all configured using domain accounts.  Every site in IIS stopped working until I (by way of a test) added the application pool accounts to the local administrators group in which case they started working.

I've already made sure the account has read/write/execute rights for the site's virtual directory.

Is there a standard procedure for recovering from this?  How do I get my asp.net site (much less sharepoint) back online without making the app-pool account a local administrator?

*[edit]*

Okay, so for a simple asp.net site, what do I need to do to get it running?  So I tried creating a local user account for it's application pool, and gave it rights on the site's directory, and set the password in IIS.  Still, I get "service unavailable" when I browse to the site.  And the application pool *always* stops when I hit the page.

Comment: Honestly, you're probably better off rebuilding your IIS server from the ground up. Permissions and ACLs can be very confusing with IIS involved and everything won't play nice.

Comment: Thanks, Nathan.  What do you mean by "rebuild"?  I'm scared!  If "rebuild" means to uninstall IIS and reinstall it, it will mess up my Sharepoint.

Comment: By rebuild...starting from scratch with a new server (well, Windows install) and restoring everything. I believe with Sharepoint you can easily back it up and restore it to a new running instance of Sharepoint.

Comment: ugh - I don't want to do that.  Surely there's another way.